# De que forma é possível lançar mensagens de log em uma aplicação COBOL?

Tags: log, cobol, logging

Considerando os ambientes Mainstream com [COBOL Enterprise for z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/br-pt/marketplace/ibm-cobol) e um ambiente Linux genérico com [GnuCOBOL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/), ambos devem laçar mensagens de erro, exceções e logs do sistema.

Considerando que possuo acesso completo ao código fonte, bem como os recursos para modificá-lo, que tipo de mensagens de log, erros e exceções podem ser gerados utilizando COBOL em suas versões mais recentes ([**ISO COBOL2002**](http://jornadat.com.br/as-grandes-mudancas-do-iso-cobol-2002/))? É possível centralizar esses logs gerados pela aplicação?

Comment: Acho que além da linguagem, é importante nesse caso ter mais informações: qual o ambiente de execução? (Linux/algum S.O. de mainframe antigo?) qual implementação de Cobol? Você pode alterar a aplicação se for necessário, ou ela não tem acesso aos fontes/formas de fazer um rebuild?

Comment: Com amplo acesso ao código e rebuild. Ambientes Linux com OpenCOBOL e ambiente oficial IBM COBOL. COBOL 2002 ou superior